# Problem with Instapy while accepting cookies

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, instapy

Here's the problem with my my app - it seems that instapy is not able to locate input boxes due to "Allow cookies" mirror.
I'm new to python, so please be understanding.
What could be the possible solution?

```
InstaPy configurationInstaPy Version: 0.6.16.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ._.Workspace in use: "C:/Users/barto/InstaPy"OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOINFO [2023-04-02 01:41:20] [montyandmacythegoldens] Session started!ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooINFO [2023-04-02 01:41:23] [montyandmacythegoldens] - Cookie file not found, creating cookie...WARNING [2023-04-02 01:41:33] [montyandmacythegoldens] Login A/B test detected! Trying another string...WARNING [2023-04-02 01:41:38] [montyandmacythegoldens] Could not pass the login A/B test. Trying last string...ERROR [2023-04-02 01:41:43] [montyandmacythegoldens] Login A/B test failed!b"Message: Unable to locate element: //div[text()='Log In']\nStacktrace:\nRemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8\nWebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5\nNoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:392:5\nelement.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:134:16\n"Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\instapy\login_util.py", line 337, in login_userlogin_elem = browser.find_element(^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 831, in find_elementreturn self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in executeself.error_handler.check_response(response)File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_responseraise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //button[text()='Log In']Stacktrace:RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:392:5element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:134:16
```

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\instapy\login_util.py", line 343, in login_userlogin_elem = browser.find_element(^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 831, in find_elementreturn self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in executeself.error_handler.check_response(response)File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_responseraise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[text()='Log in']Stacktrace:RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:392:5element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:134:16
```

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\instapy\login_util.py", line 350, in login_userlogin_elem = browser.find_element(^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 831, in find_elementreturn self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in executeself.error_handler.check_response(response)File "C:\Users\barto\InstagramBOT.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_responseraise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[text()='Log In']Stacktrace:RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:392:5element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:134:16
```

```
....................................................................................................................................CRITICAL [2023-04-02 01:41:43] [montyandmacythegoldens] Unable to login to Instagram! You will find more information in the logs above.''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

```
INFO [2023-04-02 01:41:46] [montyandmacythegoldens] Sessional Live Report:|> No any statistics to show
```

```
[Session lasted 31.97 seconds]OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOINFO [2023-04-02 01:41:46] [montyandmacythegoldens] Session ended!ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

Code looks like this:

```
from credentials import login, password
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

# login credentials
insta_username = login
insta_password = password

comments = ['Nice shot! @{}',
        'I love your profile! @{}',
        'Your feed is an inspiration :thumbsup:',
        'Just incredible :open_mouth:',
        'What camera did you use @{}?',
        'Love your posts @{}',
        'Looks awesome @{}',
        'Getting inspired by you @{}',
        ':raised_hands: Yes!',
        'I can feel your passion @{} :muscle:']

# get an InstaPy session!
# set headless_browser=True to run InstaPy in the background
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
                  password=insta_password,
                  headless_browser=False, want_check_browser=False)

with smart_run(session):
  """ Activity flow """     
        
  
  # activity        
  session.like_by_tags(["natgeo"], amount=3)
```

I had some previous errors with checking browser, and locating geckodriver, but it seems I resolved that.